# Angular directive inside template, HOWTO receive parameters (summerNote editor)

Tags: angularjs, directive, summernote

I use the summernote editor as an angularized version, as a directive, from here: https://github.com/summernote/angular-summernote

When doing this:

```
<summernote config='options'></summernote>
....
controllerfn = function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.options = {
        height: 300
    }
}
```

all works very well.

When using this approach inside a directive, it does not:

```
angular
    .module('common')
        .directive('textArea', textAreaFn);

textAreaFn.$inject = [ '$compile' ];

function textAreaFn($compile) {
    return {
        require: "?ngModel",
        scope: { 
        },
        template: "<summernote config='options'></summernote>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.options = {
                height: 300
            };
          $compile(element.contents())(scope)


        }
    };
}
```

Does anybody know why this does not work? And how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: The summernote editor does not handle the options I provide, such as the height set here.

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly buried in the angular documentation but there is a concept of pre and post linking functions. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#pre-linking-function

Code in the pre-linking function will be executed before any child elements are linked.

```
angular
    .module('common')
        .directive('textArea', textAreaFn);

textAreaFn.$inject = [ '$compile' ];

function textAreaFn($compile) {
    return {
        require: "?ngModel",
        scope: {
        },
        template: "<summernote config='options'></summernote>",
        link: {
          pre: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.options = {
                height: 300
            };
          },
          post: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            // code you want to run after all child elements have been linked
          }
        }
    };
}
```